# Ajax.BeginForm doesn't call onSuccess

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

In ASP.NET MVC 3 application I use Ajax.BeginForm to post writed text to controller.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Post", "Forum", new {threadId = Model.Thread.Id  }, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "PostReply" }))
{
    <div id="reply-area">
        <h3 style="border-bottom:1px solid black">POST REPLY</h3>

        <span id="post-error" class="error-message"></span>
        <textarea rows="1" cols="1" id="post-textarea" name="Content">    </textarea>

         <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit"/>

     </div>
}
```

In controller I have

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Post(int threadId,PostModel model)
 {
     bool Success = false;
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        Success=Unit.ForumFacade.CreatePost(Unit.ForumFacade.GetThreadByID(threadId), model.Content,  CurrentUserId);
        if (Success == true) return View("PostSuccess");
    }

    return Json("fsdfds");
}
```

And in javascript I have this

```
function PostReply(isRequestSuccessed) {
    alert("asdasd");
    if (isRequestSuccessed==false) {
        $("#post-error").html("Please Try Again");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#post-error").html("");
    }
}
```

The problem is that Javascript's function doesn't firing and isntead the alert, my browser(Firefox) returns me pop-up to download application/json file.
What is wrong here?

Comment: Please refer this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061063/mvc-3-ajax-beginform-does-a-full-post-back

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure you have included the following script to your page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and that you have enabled unobtrusive javascript in your web.config:

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

This is what makes `Ajax.*` helpers such as `Ajax.BeginForm` to work.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to attach jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js ))))

Comment: Thank you Darin. I've almost gone crazy only to find out that the Shared View I was using was missing the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js reference.

Comment: You can download jquery.unobstrusive-ajax.js from  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/

Comment: I needed to update it as I updated to a newer jQuery version.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to "Darin Dimitrov" and [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7281319/3649914) for pointing out a lot about this. But just adding to it, I know this might be simple but this got me,

My mistake was that I thought

```
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

and

```
 jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
```

where the same when they aren't. Make sure you use the "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" found in Nuget.

[Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax)

Answer (score 0):

It is a much nicer solution when you give your form an Id and then attach the submit event in a separate javascript file (using jQuery) and handle the post there

html:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Post", "Forum", new {threadId = Model.Thread.Id  }, new {id = "formid" }))
{
 ...
```

Javascript:

```
$("#formid").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                //do your success logic
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: In this case you can just use the `Html.BeginForm` version

Answer (score 0):

here the best solution i have found 100% fix..

http://www.learnsharecorner.com/asp-net/ajax-begin-form-onsuccess-is-not-working-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: "File not found" isn't the best solution, but another problem