# ASP.NET MVC 3 + jQuery Ajax JSON - Prevent JSON from opening in new page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, json, jquery

I have an Action Method that returns a JSON-serialized object. The problem I'm having is that the JSON returned is opening in a new page, instead of being processed by the "success" function of the jquery.Ajax method.

Here's the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddAssignment(AssignmentViewModel avm)
{
    db.Assignments.Add(new Assignment
    {
        Name       = avm.Name,
        DueDate    = DateTime.Parse(avm.DueDate),
        CourseID   = avm.CourseID,
        IsComplete = false
    });
    db.SaveChanges();

    avm.Course = db.Courses
        .Where(x => x.CourseID == avm.CourseID)
        .SingleOrDefault()
        .Name;

    return Json(avm);
}
```

Here's the View (form):

```
@model Fooburg.Mvc.Models.AssignmentViewModel

<h2 style="margin: 0 0 24px 0">Add Assignment:</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddAssignment",
    "Assignments",
    FormMethod.Post,
    new { @id = "add-assignment-form" }))
{
    <dl class="tabular">
        <dt>Course:</dt>
        <dd>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CourseID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Courses, "CourseID", "Name"))
        </dd>
        <dt>Assignment:</dt>
        <dd>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
        </dd>
        <dt>Due Date:</dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DueDate, new { @class = "date" })
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" });
                });
            </script>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Assignment" id="new-assignment-submit" />
    </p>
}
```

And here's the javascript:

```
$(function () {
        $('#add-assignment-form').submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#output').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I have tried the `event.stopPropogation()` method, but didn't change my problem

**EDIT:** I've updated my javascript to the following, but I'm still getting the same result

```
$('#add-assignment-form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#output').html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Consider returning a view for non-Javascript-enabled browsers.

Comment: Are you including the ajax script?  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5061145/409259

Comment: @adrift, that script is needed only when using unobtrusive Ajax MVC helpers.

Comment: Like SLaks said, why on earth are you not just using `return Json(avm);`

Comment: @Dismissile -I changed my controller action. Edited to reflect the change. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `return false;` or `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the browser from submitting the form normally.

Comment: Thank you, adding both return false and event.preventDefault() has no effect

Comment: Hmmm, I'm getting a "$ is not defined"

Comment: There's your problem; you don't have jQuery.

Comment: lol, jquery is included (of course), i think it might be where exactly that javascript is located in the HTML...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5244/discussion-between-erox-and-slaks)

Answer (score 1):

Just specify

```
return false;
```

after your `$.ajax()` call

**UPDATE**

```
$(function () {
        $('#add-assignment-form input[type=submit]').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#output').html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, adding return false has no effect. See above edits to see my edited javascript

Comment: See the updated code. Bind the click event of the submit button. This should do. Please check

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here,

Use `Ajax.BeginForm()` instead of `Html.BeginForm()` that you would use like

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm( "AddAssignment", "Assignments",
      new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "output"})) {
  ...
}
```

and get rid of the javascript code.

---

Or call `event.prevendDefault()` in

```
$('#add-assignment-form').submit(function (event) {
    // ...
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Following the conventional wisdom I'm trying to accomplish this via jquery only. However, following your suggestion for the jquery edit, my situation doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if there are other javascript errors on the page that might be causing this unexpected behaviour? I would suggest Firebug for FF or Javascript Console for Chrome.

Also, I've noticed that sometime FF has issues if you don't specify the script type, so make sure your type is set to "text/javascript".

hth,

-covo